# is it possible to connect to AWS RDS db instance(postgres) through ubuntu server installed out of aws(in my local)?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services

Actually i have to migrate the data from `AWS RDS postgres` to on premises postgres.

For this i have to establish connectivity between my `AWS RDS db instance` and on premises(ubuntu server).

I have already configured the **inbound rules** of security group in my `RDS DB instance`. But still i am not able to connect to AWS RDS db instance directly through my **Ubuntu Machine**..

Is there any issue with the **firewall** of my VM??

Error which i am getting:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
       Is the server running on host "XXXXXX" (X.X.X.X/X) and accepting
       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The database setting for publicly accessible is set to NO.
There are both public as well as private subnet associated with my RDS instance.
i have provided the type as postgreSQL , port 5432 , protocol TCP, source custom ip (X.X.X.X/32)
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to provide details of your setup>? is the rds public? is it in public subnet? What are the subnet groups, and all other relevant data.

Comment: Are you effectively asking "How can I connect from my own local computer to an Amazon RDS database"? Yes, this is possible. What is the database setting for `Publicly Accessible`? Is the database in a public subnet? What is the configuration of the Security Group associated with the database? Please Edit your question to provide these additional details rather than answering via a comment.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, the Publicly Accessible setting is set to NO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an Amazon RDS database from the Internet:

- Set the database to `Publicly Accessible = Yes` (This resolves the DNS name to a Public IP address)
- Put the database in a **Public Subnet** (Mixing public & private subnets in a Subnet Group is not advisable, because the results will be random! It will only be in one subnet at any time, but might change subnets when upgraded or failover is triggered.)
- Add a **Security Group** that allows Inbound access on the appropriate port (PostgreSQL = 5432) from your IP address
- Reference the database via its **DNS Name** shown in the Amazon RDS management console

Alternatively, keep the database in a **Private Subnet** and access via a **VPN Connection** or by **Port Forwarding via a Bastion Server**.